# Discord.py commands.BotMissingPermissions

Tags: discord.py

I want to send an error message when my bot's role is insufficient, but I can't. I tried all the "MissingRole" commands but none of them work...

```
@Bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
.
.
.
   await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        await ctx.message.add_reaction("❌")
        aEmbed = discord.Embed(
            title=f"**__Error__**",
            description="Whatever you want the bot to say to the user",
            colour=discord.Colour.red()
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=aEmbed)
        return
```

This is how I made the "BotMissingPermissions". The code is pretty basic, it just puts a "X" reaction to the message that made the error and then sends an embed saying what went wrong then returns so that it can continue functioning without any problems

Also the response you told the bot to do (`await ctx.channel.send("Something something")`) could be changed to `await ctx.send("Something")`.